# Java paintComponent()

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent, jcomponent

java paintComponent()

```
     class MyClass extends JComponent {
         void paintComponent() {
             //code for class here
          }
     }

     class myTestClass extends JPanel {
         MyClass temp = new MyClass();

         void paintComponent() {
               super.paintComponent();


      static void main(String[] a) {
           JFrame f = new JFrame();
              //Does the temp have to be added to the panel before it can be repainted
      } 
     } //End Class
```

I know that the `JPanel` goes into the `JFrame`.  But does the class (`MyClass`) have to be added to the `JPanel` for the `paintComponent()` will repaint the child node with `super.paintComponent()`. I would think that this would be the case. If this is the case then `temp.repaint()` should repaint that specific component anywhere it is called if the `super.paintComponent()` repaints the component.

This seems to be an answer that nobody has or at least that nobody really has posted. My explanation might be a little of so I will try and to clarify it here.

If I have several classes that extend JComponent and I want them to all be used in class so I can repaint them.  Lets say one is a circle, rectangle, square, and etc..............

If they all have a `paintComponent()` with a `super.paintComponent()` they should be able to be repainted with `VariableName.repaint();`

Do they have to be added to the `JPanel` that is going to hold them as content. And can they be call to be `repaint()` be called from anywhere in the code (I think that this is the case).

Driver class:

```
  class MyMainDriverClass {
    A a = new A();
    B b = new B();
    C c = new C();

void someClass() {
   a.repaint();
   b.repaint();
   c.repaint();  //this should repaint the components if the JPanel is inside of the JFrame 
                 //(I didn't put this code in)
 }
}
```

This should repaint the component above if all the classes that are created have a `paintComponent()`.

Doug Hauf

Comment: What is your specific question? Your examples are not valid at all. Please effort to make a good a question and you will have a good answer surely

Comment: There is usually little need to call `repaint()` manually. (The reason for doing so is to force an invalidation of the drawn graphics - not to draw them to begin with.)

Comment: What I want to do is make any class extend JComponent which then can be added to any other class. I then want to be able to call the repaint() method of the variable that will call the paintComponent(). I have been doing a lot of examples in just graphics and want to be able to repaint() components on the screen at will. I think that for the most part a person would have to call repaint() all that often but I was trying to make a poker game and wanted to have everything in graphics. 
T

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes `MyClass` will need to be added to something that is displayable on the screen in order to be painted.  The reasoning here is that `MyClass` extends `JComponent` and `myTestClass` extends `JPanel`, they are in no way related, so calling `super.paintComponent` from within `myTestClass` won't paint or update `MyClass` in any way.

Any thing you want to be painted must be added to a displayable container.

Take a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for more details about painting.

You can call `repaint` on any `Component` individual or on it's parent container as required

Comment: Thank you for the help. If my main class extends JPanel and I make a JFrame and added the panel to the frame and have my panel.add(MyClass) I then should be able to repaint the component when ever I call temp.repaint().

Comment: All things been equal, yes

Comment: If I have a class that extends JComponent with a paintComponent() I should be able to call repaint() from a different class as long as my component is added to some container like a JPanel. Correct. You wouldn't happen to have a simple working example would you????

Comment: So long as the target component is on a displayable container, then yes, you can call it's `repaint` method and it will schedule a repaint request...